# Does talking to Sonic's friends deplete memory tokens?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

Talking to Sonic's friends or Sage for the main story or sidequests shows a cutscene of Sonic using up memory tokens. However, I've noticed that the number of memory tokens shown in the HUD doesn't decrease.

Are memory tokens a limited resource that get used up when talking to one of Sonic's friends? (IE: Using tokens to talk to Amy in one spot means I'll need to gather more tokens before I can talk to her again). Or are conversation requirements based on a cumulative total of memory tokens?